# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv, ruby-2.3

I'm trying to setup rbenv to use with fastlane. I follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x). I've installed rbenv

`rbenv install 2.3.1`

Then updated it so the version points to:

`rbenv local 2.3.1` => `2.3.1 (set by /Users/pepe/Development/test-ios/.ruby-version)`

I then try to install bundler:

`gem install bundler` and get the following error:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

And running following gives me:

`rbenv which gem
/Users/pernillau-ext/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/gem`

`which gem
/Users/pernillau-ext/.rbenv/shims/gem`

Obviously rbenv points to one installation of gem and the system (Mac OS  X 10.116) comes with preinstalled ruby and gems which is installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory. So, what am I missing here? Why is gem command using the wrong version.

EDIT:

My bash_profile:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/pepe/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
export GEM_PATH=/Users/pepe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/pernillau-ext/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/pernillau-ext/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
PATH="$(perl -e 'print join(":", grep { not $seen{$_}++ } split(/:/, $ENV{PATH}))')"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

Comment: Output of `gem env home` after `rbenv local 2.3.1`?

Comment: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0` and `rbenv local 2.3.1` gives nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try mooving things in `$PATH` a little. Move rbenv to the front of the `$PATH`.

`$PATH` in your shell should look roughtly like (pseudocode):

```
{rbenv shims} : {rbenv bin} : {system paths}
```

Comment: My path looks like: `/Users/pepe/.rbenv/shims:/Users/pepe/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/pepe/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/pepe/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

Comment: try `/Users/pepe/.rbenv/shims:/Users/pepe/.rbenv/bin:/Users/pepe/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local‌​/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/‌​usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/‌​X11/bin:/Users/pepe/‌​Library/Android/sdk/‌​tools:/Users/pepe/Li‌​brary/Android/sdk/pl‌​atform-tools`

Comment: I don't know how to get that specific path. Look at my bash_profile in my updated question.